# Need grid and function dynamic using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code for js part:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //For first textArea
  $("#showTextArea1").click(function(){
    $('#area1').css('display','block');
    $('#addingText1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#add1').click(function(){
      var text = $('textarea#txtarea1').val();
      if(text!=''){
        $('p#p1').text(text);  $('#area1').css('display','none');
      }
      else{
        $('#error1').css('display','block');
      }
    });
    $('#remove1').click(function(){
      $('#area1').css('display','none');
      $('#addingText1').css('display', 'block');
    });
  });

  //For 1st title
  $("#showTitle1").click(function(){
    $('#area1').css('display','block');
    $('#addingText1').css('display', 'none');
    $('.add1').click(function(){
      var text = $('.forTitle1').val();
      if(text!=''){
        $('h2#h21').text(text);
        $('#area1').css('display','none');
      }
      else{

        $('#titleError1').css('display','block');
      }
    });
    $('#remove1').click(function(){
      $('#area1').css('display','none');
      $('#addingText1').css('display', 'block');
    }); 
  });     
});

function refreshPage(){
  window.location.reload();
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    
    </head>
    <body>
    <section class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <article class="col-md-4">
            <div class="border">
            <p id="p1"></p>
            <h2 id="h21"></h2>
            <div id="addingText1">
            <h4 class="title" id="showTextArea1">Add Description</h4>
            <h4 class="subTitle" id="showTitle1">Add Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="area1" style="display: none;">
            <textarea id="txtarea1" class="forTitle1" placeholder="Add Description"></textarea>
            <input type="button" class="add1" value="+" id="add1" />
            <input type="button" class="removeclass1" value="-" id="remove1" />
            <p id="error1" style="display: none;">Please enter text</p>
            <p id="titleError1" style="display: none;">Please enter title</p>
            </div>

            </div>
        </article>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6 text-right">
            <button class="resetProperty" type="reset" onClick="refreshPage()">Clear All</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I want is, I want if I put 9 in jQuery the 9 divs will be created automatically and If I write 7, 7 grids will be created and I also want the functions will work dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- HTML Code -->
<input type ="text" id="count"/> 
<input type="button" id="create" value="Create"/> 
<div id="divs"/>

<!-- JS Code -->
<script>
$('#create').on('click',function(){
    $('#divs').html('')
    console.log( $('#count').val());
   for(i=0; i < parseInt( $('#count').val()) ; i++){
        $('#divs').append('<div style="height:100px; width:100px ;margin:10px;background:red;"></div>');
   }
});
</script>
```